# Chromecast not found until something else casts

Tags: wireless-networking, chromecast

My laptop can cast to my Chromecast, but only after something else (like my phone) begins casting to it. Until the second something else casts the laptop shows 'no cast devices found', and the second the phone begins casting it appears to the laptop - at which point I can disconnect that and connect the laptop.

Any idea what is going on here? There’s only one Wi-Fi network, though it does have 2G and 5G - don’t know if that’s a factor. Seems super odd.

Answer (score 0):

The network adapter of your laptop has a problem. If you are using Windows 10, try opening the `Connect app`and then trying to connect to wireless display.

Comment: its linux, and i doubt this is the cause because this has also happened previously on a different windows laptop.